# Get post parameter in firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can i access post parameter in firebase  cloud functions. I used postman to test the function, it is returning undefined, i am returning the passed value back. this is my code (type script)

```
exports.testParam = functions.https.onRequest((request,response)=>{
    const x = request.params['username'];
    response.send(`data passed is ${x}`);
});
```

I am sending a form url encoded parameter named `username`. How can i access the post parameter in firebase cloud function